# Javascript: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, data-layers

I have simple script in new version of Javascript which I need to use in Google Tag Manager.

Google Tag Manager not supporting new Javascript so my script is necessary to be in older version of Javascript.

I already changed all my `const's` and `let's` to `var's` and script still not working.

How I can change it to older version of Javascript and make it functional in Google Tag Manager?

**My Script:**

```
function getFromDataLayer(key) { 
    var result = null; 
    dataLayer.push(function() { 
        var value = this.get(key);
        if (value) {
            result = value;
        }
    });
    return result;    
};

var ecom = getFromDataLayer('ecommerce.purchase.products');

var filterValue = "Krups";
var filteredProducts = ecom.filter(val.brand.includes(filterValue));
//console.log(filteredProducts);
return filteredProducts.reduce((n, {price}) => n + parseInt(price), 0)
```

Comment: Arrow functions were introduced in ES6 (ES2015).

Comment: @madzong how I can change arrow function to version of older JS?

Comment: Turn it into a regular function with `function() {}`.

Comment: @madzong like this? 

return filteredProducts.reduce((n, {price}) function() {
    n + parseInt(price), 0)
  }

but syntax is not right